# External references in JustinRainbow/JsonSchema

Tags: php, jsonschema

I've been digging the way to use external references. I found that all references should be loaded to schema storage before using them in `$ref`.

I tried different ways to achieve that and finally there was no any exceptions:

```
$schemaStorage = new SchemaStorage();

$schemaStorage->addSchema('file://foo.json', json_decode(file_get_contents(realpath(__DIR__."/foo.json")));
$schemaStorage->addSchema('file://bar.json', json_decode(file_get_contents(realpath(__DIR__."/bar.json")));

$validator = return new Validator(new Factory($schemaStorage));

$validator->validate($jsonData, json_decode(file_get_contents(realpath(__DIR__."/main.json"))));
```

Then in my schema I tried to reference on defined schema id:

```
{
  "title": "foobar schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
       "$ref": "file://foo.json"
    },
    "bar": {
       "$ref": "file://bar.json"
    }
  },
  "required": ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

But, still - all references are not validated even they are correctly preloaded. Only the main schema is used for validation. Maybe someone knows what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: By "not validated", do you mean an error is thrown or that the validation process believes your data is valid?

Comment: @Relequestual The library I'm using https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema. 
The validation process passes without errors, like it's all valid

Comment: In which case, the references MAY be working, but your schemas MAY be wrong. Have you tried replacing the references with your schemas to test this theory? If a reference isn't resolved, you should get an error.

Comment: I checked my theory referencing local reference from the same file like `"$ref": "#/definitions/foo"`. So with this case the validation fails.

Comment: Both foo references from same file and separate one are identical. The only thing I change is $ref

Comment: In which case, I can’t see anything you’ve done wrong. Maybe you could make a fiddle so I can take a closer look and rule out some things? I don’t have a PHP environment these days http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: @Relequestual it looks more like an issue with library itself. Will not spend more time on it, it lacks the documentation on that. Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome. You may want to delete your question. Feel free to ask other questions. JSON Schema team watch that jsonschema tag =]